# Exporting .pdf from Illustrator causes black to look green when printed

Tags: adobe-illustrator, digital-printing

It appears when I am making something in Illustrator to send to the printer that is vector artwork but includes a raster image, any vector artwork that is black has a green tint to it when printed. I have tried playing with the appearance of black and trying full CMYK black vs. registration black and it never comes out right. When I print something that is vector artwork alone it comes out true black.

Comment: This sounds like a printer issue and most likely can't be solved here. Can you add pictures of the original and the resulting print? Also, adding system and printer specs could help.

Comment: If this is a home/office inkjet printer, most can't handle CMYK image. Check the documentation for your printer to see whether it supports CMYK documents.

Comment: This is about a Laser Printer-> When I put an image over a vector it prints in different colors. It gets lighter/brighter where the image overlaps the vector. This issue does not happen when I print the same file in an inkjet printer. My solution for this case is: I rasterize everything before print it. Or, I open the .ai file in Photoshop to print it.